# Is it acceptable to omit genitive noun endings in some cases?

Tags: noun, genitive

I read this sentence on a news website *(bild.de)* today:

> Die beiden riesigen O-Buchstaben **des Wahrzeichen** von Los Angeles
>   waren mit weißen und schwarzen Planen jeweils zu einem E abgewandelt
>   worden.

Shouldn’t it be *des Wahrzeichens*? (Dictionary lists *Zeichens* in genitive).
Is this a mistake, or is it sometimes acceptable to omit the genitive noun ending?

Comment: Yes, it should. This is a mistake. Note, however, that German is currently undergoing a long-term language change where inflections will probably eventually lost, so what's wrong today will be optional another day and normal eventually.

Comment: What Kilian wrote is absolutely true: German is slowly changing all the time (like all living languages), and you can watch, that the genitive-s is omitted very often, and the rate of missing genitive-s's is increasing over the last years. It still is considered to be an error, but you will see this error more and more often in the future, and I bet, that in a few decades the genitive-s will officially be labeled as »optional«. But now, in 2017, it still is mandatory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is a mistake. It not acceptable to leave out the declension ending except in very few cases where different declensions are possible.

Comment: OK, thanks! I guess it is something that language learners should keep in mind - that there will be mistakes even in reputable native language sources. Although it is definitely very confusing for beginners who are just trying to make some sense of the grammar.

Comment: @Viktor Your usage of the word ‘reputable’ in connection (even if loose) to the *Bild* gutter paper is … daring.

Comment: Oh, ok, I didn't realize, thanks for the notice. I was just looking for some news website to use as a reading exercise, and decided to go with "the most visited", and I think it brought me to Bild. This is way off-topic, but since it has been brought up, it would be nice if you could recommend some other source instead - more reputable, and hopefully more careful with their grammar too :-)

Comment: @Viktor There are quite a few. I personally prefer sueddeutsche.de (from the daily *Süddeutsche Zeitung)* and zeit.de (from the weekly newspaper *ZEIT).* Both are liberal to left-ish newspapers; if you’re more conservative, then faz.net (from the *Frankfurter Allgemeine)* may be your type of paper.